# Django forms with slider

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

Is it possible to use a slider with Django Forms with Crispy Forms?

I am using Foundation and the example code is below.

```
<div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-end="100">
  <span class="slider-handle" data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1"></span>
  <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount">
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help you. Always nice when people say thank you and interact with the person who helps them. If you need anything else let me know.

Comment: awesome.  thanks so very much.  will test it out asap.  cheers.

Answer (score -2):

After burning a couple days playing with this, I am convinced that the jquery approach is not the best way to tackle this.

I would recommend just going with the Crispy-form template approach

```
Field('slider', template="custom-slider.html")
```

good luck.